# I cant install sdl because it has unmet dependencies

Tags: apt

My input is:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
```

and the output is:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.

libsdl-image1.2-dev : Depends: libjpeg-dev
Depends: libtiff4-dev but it is not going to be installed

libsdl1.2-dev : Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libpulse-dev but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libxt-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libpulse-dev libxt-dev
```

If that doesn't work you may use aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libsdl1.2-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libpulse-dev libxt-dev
```

Comment: i typed it in however when i try to compile an sdl program it wont compile;

Comment: the output of the command is: Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.    
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
 LANGUAGE = (unset),
 LC_ALL = (unset),
 LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Comment: @rahman can you edit your question instead please.

Answer (score 0):

To fix unmet dependencies, use `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Comment: i did that already and it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You may have to enable the "Source code" repository in the Software and Updates program.

Comment: i enabled the source code and repeated what you said however im still ending with the same output

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` before trying again.